# How to get the dependencies of pypi-hosted eggs programmatically?

Tags: python, dependencies, setup.py, pypi, egg

On https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc it is claimed one can retrieve the dependencies of an egg, using the `release_data()`-method.

However, the documented `requires`-property seems not to exist, this is my attempt:

```
import xmlrpclib

client = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('https://pypi.python.org/pypi')

data = client.release_data('Products.CMFPlone', '4.3.4')

reqs = data['requires']

print reqs # ---> KeyError: 'requires'

print data.keys() # ---> 'requires' is not amongst the keys
```

Am I missing something?